# Precompile header in CPP project and C generated from wsdl file

Tags: c++, visual-c++, svcutil.exe

I'm creating simple web service client in CPP. I have generated source files from WSDL with help of `svcutil` ans `wsutil` utilites. At the end I got web service interface `header` and `C` file.

When I include C file into my console application that uses precompiled header I have message:

```
Error   3   error C1853: 'Debug\TestLib3.pch' precompiled header file is from a previous version of the compiler, or the precompiled header is C++ and you are using it from C (or vice versa)
```

How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The C compiler cannot use a .pch file that was generated by the C++ compiler.  Two basic options:

- Rename the .c file to .cpp, likely to work fine on an auto-generated source file.
- Right-click the .c file in the Solution Explorer window, Properties, C/C++, Precompiled headers, "Precompiled Header" option.  Change it to "Not using".  You may also need to modify C++ source files that #includes the .h file, it is liable to require `extern "C" {}` around the #include directive so the C++ compiler knows that the .h file contains C declarations.  You'll know this is needed when you get linker errors that show the mangled name of the function.